# Show that convergence in one metric implies convergence in the other using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metrix space. Consider $\rho : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ given by
>
> $$ \rho_d(x,y) := \frac{d(x,y)}{1 + d(x,y)},\ x,y \in X.$$
> Assume that $(d_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of metrics on a space $X$. Consider
>
> $$d(x,y) := \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} 2^{-k} \rho_{d_k}(x,y), \ x,y \in X.$$
>
> Show that $d$ is a metric on $X$, and that a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in $(X,d)$ if and only if it converges in $(X,d_k)$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

How do we show that a sequence converges in $(X,d)$ iff it converges in $(X,d_k)$ using LDCT?
I know this problem can be done without that, but I am curious as to how we can apply the dominated convergence theorem and why that theorem would show up in a problem that doesn't seem to have much to do with measure theory and integrals.

Comment: The dominating series is $\sum 2^{-k}$. This is  a straight-forward application of DCT (applied to counting measure on $\mathbb N$).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy hi thank you for the reply. I can do the forward direction, but i still cannot figure out the backward direction. How do we apply LDCT?

Comment: I've edited your post to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't). In the future you should do the same so that users with similar questions will have an easier time finding this ^_^